# Conditional CSS in CSS not working

Tags: css, conditional-statements

so I have this css code:

```
.onetoone{
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 878px;
    [if ! IE] height: 1241px;
    [if IE] height: 241px;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
```

However I don't see any different height on .onetoone in IE and Firefox, both are still have the same 214px height. It should has a 1232px height in firefox and 241px height in IE 8, right?

What did I miss?

Thanks for all your answers.

Comment: That's not how conditional code works. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) for examples.

Comment: @MrLister, I also thought so, but look at [this](http://www.conditional-css.com/advanced)

Comment: Or you can see http://www.conditional-css.com/demo/advanced.css for more detail

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't tell that was what you meant. In that case, Starx' and andriy's answers are correct.

Comment: @MrLister, I dont think its needed to know about this script. It is really not my type. Check my answer to see what i mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Have you read the usage file?

According the website, you have to write the css and compile it using its online [tool](http://www.conditional-css.com/index) and then you have include `c-css.php` to get it working.

```
@import "/media/css/c-css.php";
```

According to example from this [website](http://www.conditional-css.com/), this should fix the problem.

```
.onetoone{
    position: relative;
    margin: 10px auto 5px;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 878px;
    border: 1px solid #AAAAAA;
    behavior: url(PIE.htc);
}
[if !IE] .onetoone {
    height: 1241px;
}

[if IE] .onetoone {
    height: 241px;
}
```

After you compile it becomes a huge file like this one [here](http://pastebin.com/qYHj9wcx) and you include like the way I said above.

---

However, I would go with the **good old fashioned** way I knew. And it was to include different css with the conditional CSS comments

```
<!--[if IE]>
   <style>
      .onetoone {
        height: 241px;
       }
   </style>
<![endif]-->

<!--[if !IE]>
   <style>
      .onetoone {
        height: 1241px;
       }
   </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Should work either way.

---

#### Update

Instead of loading different style like the one in my example load different file in the end after loading all the main css files in this way.

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fixforie.css" />
<![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 6]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fixforie6.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: If I go with the gool old fashioned way, I should put those css comments after the main css is called right?

Comment: @Dave, Yes. Better include a css file, which contains all the patches of a IE or specific IE Version.

Comment: Starx, thank you so much. It works!
Good old fashioned way rocks many times.

Answer (score 1):

I know that this has been answered last year but I wanted to point out a method that doesn't seem to be used although the functionality has been written into the CSS2.1 specification. (See [CSS Conditional Rules Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-conditional-20121213/) for more specific details).

--

### The IE method was to do something like the following;

```
<!--[if IE]>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

As described in the [Conditional comments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment) section of the wiki.

--

Another method mentioned on here is to use [Conditional-CSS](http://www.conditional-css.com/) which seems popular but I've never heard of it and couldn't give an example of how to use it so a link will have to do! (Sry ppl).

--

### THE NEW METHOD SINCE DEC 2012:

By using [Conditional Group Rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-conditional-20121213/) you can define conditions like;

```
@media print { #navigation { display: none; } }
```

(Example taken from the specification) This will hide the navigation bar when printed.
Another [Conditional Group Rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-css3-conditional-20121213/) you can define is @SUPPORTS, for example;

```
@supports (box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red)
{
box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red;
}
```

and include "and", "or" and "not" operators like;

```
@supports ((box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red) and (border-radius: 25px))
{
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px red;
    border-radius: 25px;
}
```

This means rather than testing the clients browser, you test the features available to css and style accordingly. Unfortunately, you're unable to nest other at-rules (like @import which could be used to import a browser specific style sheet based on the availability of a css feature).

Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can load another CSS file in your HTML page for example:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/ie8.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add conditional to the class:

```
[if IE] .ie-height{  
    height: 241px;
}
```

Comment: It is important to note that inline conditional CSS is not a CSS standard. As Starx mentioned above, it will only work with the [conditional css](http://www.conditional-css.com) server-side compiler. This will have the performance drawback of not including a static file.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to follow the [HTML5 boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/) method.

In your html add the following around your html tag:

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html lang="en-us" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html lang="en-us" class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html lang="en-us" class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html lang="en-us" class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
```

So in your style you can easily specify the ie version with standard styles:

```
div.this_element { float:right; margin-top: 10px; }
lt-ie8 div.this_element { margin-top: 5px; }
```