# Apply CSS for IE9 only, But other css are applying

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9

I have to apply the `border-radius` CSS property to a button, but only when the browser is not Internet Explorer 9. Otherwise I want to use the `background-image` property.  I tried to apply the `background-image` for IE9 using conditional comments, but it is not working (the `border-radius` property from the "general" CSS is being applied to IE9 also, instead of the `background-image`).

How do I change this to make it apply the desired CSS according to the browser version?

```
/*For IE9*/
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
.PopupBtn
{
  background-image: url("../Images/new-btn.png");
  height: 28px;
  width: 99px;
  border-left-width: 0px;
  border-top-style: none;
  border-right-style: none;
  border-bottom-style: none;
  border-left-style: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<![endif]-->

/*Style.css(general)*/
.PopupBtn
{
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 1px 0px #0d0d0d;
  -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0px 2px 1px 0px #0d0d0d;
  box-shadow:inset 0px 2px 1px 0px #0d0d0d;
  background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #fffcff), color-stop(1, #000000));
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(center top, #fffcff 5%, #000000 100%);
  filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#fffcff', endColorstr='#000000');
  background-color:#fffcff;
  -moz-border-radius:22px;
  -webkit-border-radius:22px;
  border-radius:22px;
  display:inline-block;
  color:#fcfcfc;
  font:bold 13px  trebuchet ms;
  text-decoration:none;
  text-shadow:1px 0px 0px #000000;
  min-width:90px;
  height:30px;
  cursor:pointer;
  border-style:none;
}
```

Comment: [Click here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601775/conditional-css-in-css-not-working/9601850#9601850) to see a similar stackoverflow question which should be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place the **Internet Explorer Conditional Comments** on the actual web page and not in the CSS file.

Avoid adding inline CSS code.  Instead, put them in their own CSS file.  It's a good idea to separate your CSS files.  Make one for the IE "hacks" and another for your regular stylesheet.

So, for example, put your IE specific CSS in  **ie.css** file:

**ie.css**:

```
.PopupBtn {
    background-image: url("../Images/new-btn.png");
    height: 28px;
    width: 99px;
    border-left-width: 0px;
    border-top-style: none;
    border-right-style: none;
    border-bottom-style: none;
    border-left-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Place your regular stylesheet in **style.css**.

In the `<head>` tag put:

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

   <!-- [if lte IE 9]>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css">
   <![endif]-->
</head>
```

**Note:**

IE will still apply any styles from your regular style sheet that it understands.  So,
make sure the Conditional Comments and *ie.css* style sheet is applied **after** the regular style sheet.  This way, it can override any styles you don't want.

**Make sure you explicitly override any styles you don't want in ie.css, otherwise, it will "bleed" through and show up in IE**

See my JSFiddle link below.  If you run it in IE 9, you'll see a green gradient with the word "Hello" in red.  If you run it in any other browser, you should see a black gradient with the word "Hello" in white.

http://jsfiddle.net/mKrRL/

Comment: Hi, My problem is i am unable to avoid the css applying from style.css

Comment: The code you originally posted won't work.  You have the conditional comments inside your CSS file.  They need to be on the html page instead.  Move your style into separate files and add the conditional comments to the `<head>` tag of your html file--like in my example.

Comment: the first code i used in html only i.e., conditional comments, and second one is in seperate css file and linked to my page as u said in the above example. when try to run the page both css override in case of ie9. can u please elaborate.

Comment: @Jaswanth I just updated my answer with a "note" section.  Read that part.  It should explain why it's not working for you and how you can fix it.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, consider accepting it as the correct answer. You can do this by selecting the hollowed checkmark, making it green. This will let other users know your question was solved and it will also help other users, who may have the same problem, find the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

Better use jQuery for this.

```
if ($.browser.msie  && parseInt($.browser.version, 10) == 9)
 $('.PopupBtn').css({'background-image':'url(../Images/new-btn.png)','height':'28px','width':'99px'});
```

See http://api.jquery.com/css/ The advantage is that you not only have to use less code, but you can adjust everything, not just css. This is only just an example, you have to fill in the rest :)

Answer (score 1):

IE's conditional comments are actually html comments, so you cant have them in a css file they have to be in a webpage. Somewhere in you webpage you'll have

```html
<!--[if lte IE 9]>
<style>
.PopupBtn
{
background-image: url("../Images/new-btn.png");
height: 28px;
width: 99px;
border-left-width: 0px;
border-top-style: none;
border-right-style: none;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-left-style: none;
cursor: pointer;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

or even an external style sheet link betwwen the comments

Answer (score 1):

May be it will use full for You:

```
<script src="http://ie7-js.googlecode.com/svn/version/2.1(beta4)/IE9.js"> </script>
```

use this java script in head tag.